# AJAX call: Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

My ajax call fails with the message in question.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string UpdateTotalPrice(List<TicketPriceAjax> jsonTickets)
{
    // some server-side processing
    return "a string value";
}
```

The object Iʻm trying to pass

```
public class TicketPriceAjax
{
  public string Fullname { get; set; }
  public string Price { get; set; }
  public string TicketDescription { get; set; }       
}
```

My javascript which gets invoked on a change event

```
$("select.combobox").change(function(e) {
    var ticketsArray = GetTicketsArray();        
    postTotalPrice(ticketsArray);
});

function GetTicketsArray() {
    var tickets = {};
    var prices = [];
    tickets.prices = prices;

    $("#divFullNames div.row").each(function () {
        var price = {
            "Fullname": $(this).find("input").val(),
            "Price": $(this).find("select").val(),
            "TicketDescription": $(this).find(":selected").text()             
        };

        tickets.prices.push(price);
    });

    return tickets;
};


function postTotalPrice(prices) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Details.aspx/UpdateTotalPrice",
        data: JSON.stringify(prices),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            UpdateTotalPrice(data);
        },
        error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('error!', data, textStatus, jqXHR);
        }
    });
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the JSON that you're sending to the server. I think you have a root object and then array of objects. What the function is expecting is simply an array of objects (no root). An easy way to tell what format it's expecting is to create a dummy `List<TicketPriceAjax>` and serialize it to JSON and then make sure that the structure matches what you're passing in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change data part to this

```
data: JSON.stringify({jsonTickets:prices})

Your webmethod expects a parameter with name jsonTickets so you need to specify parameter name in data part.
```

Also you do not need to assign tickets.prices simply create an array and push objects in it and pass it to webmethod.This way you are creating a list and than assigning list to its property prices and in webmethod you are expecting a list.

```
var tickets = [];
$("#divFullNames div.row").each(function () {
    var price = {
        "Fullname": $(this).find("input").val(),
        "Price": $(this).find("select").val(),
        "TicketDescription": $(this).find(":selected").text()             
    };

    tickets.push(price);
```

This  will pass list to webmethods.

Comment: Now the server-side call is invoked, but the c# List parameter is empty, while I can print my array with an alert on the javescript side.

Comment: There you go. Was at work when I asked the question and totally forgot about it.